# Bolt dimensions for Peloton cleat

Tags: pedals, cleat

I cant find this answer anywhere but what is the screw size of the Peloton sclip that goes onto the cleat?  I need a longer screw for my shoe but cant determine the thread size to make that determination.

Comment: I’m not sure about those cleats specifically, but most bolts on bikes are metric. It’s most likely M5 just like any other cleat bolt.

Comment: Just to clarify, by "clip", I assume you mean the bolt that fixes the cleat to the shoe? Of which there are 3?

Comment: Yes it’s the bolt that fastens it to the clear. M5 looks to big but I couldn’t totally be wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Peloton had some custom shoe with odd-ball fitting that you have to buy.  If the shoe is a generic "3 bolt" shoe for road bolts then it will be a M5 x 0.8 standard thread form, which you can buy at any hardware store.  Or steal your waterbottle cage bolt.     If the "sclip" on the cleat is somehow different, please add a photo.

Comment: Your other option is to take a bolt from the other shoe, and go to a hardware store and look for a match.  Get spares too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All 3-bolt shoe plates are M5 (5mm by 0.8mm per thread). So are 2-bolt. That's the thread size insofar as the wider world is concerned. That's not really what you care about.

What you ideally want is a Look Delta cleat bolt that's the right length for your shoe. They are funny little bolts and can be hard to find in just the right length if the stock ones aren't working for reasons like you're encountering. But, you need them to be low-profile like the stock ones are.

[image: stock delta]

If you are forced to improvise from the hardware store or from what most bike shops will have, the best you can probably do is M5 button head bolts with large diameter washers. The total stack will probably be thicker than proper Look or clone bolts, so they may poke out or come close to it.

[image]

Comment: You can get bolts for road cleats of different lengths. Standard is 8mm but 10 and 13mm are available. Be careful though with bolts from hardware stores. The heads may be too high and catch in the pedal, making release impossible.

Comment: I was browsing McMaster-Carr. There's a listing for extra-wide flanged head bolts, with a 12.8mm flange diameter and a 3.2mm tall head. My SPD-SL bolts are a bit over 13mm wide, and its head appears to be not much more than 2mm tall. I'm going to guesstimate that a 3.2mm tall head would (just barely) be flush with my cleat surface. It seems possible that this might do in a pinch. https://www.mcmaster.com/bolts/thread-size~m5/rounded-head-screws/flanged-rounded-head-screws/